# error while running build android app using java it might be because of implementation ("com.a:androidnetworking:1.0.5")

Tags: java, android, dependencies, build.gradle

error message Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.

This full build error messgae -

```
failed Download info

:app:checkDebugAarMetadata
:app:mapDebugSourceSetPaths
:app:mergeDebugResources
:app:processDebugMainManifest
:app:mergeDebugAssets
:app:mergeDebugJavaResource
:app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses
:app:desugarDebugFileDependencies
:app:mergeDebugNativeLibs
:app:writeDebugSigningConfigVersions
org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionNotFoundException: Could not find com.androidnetworking:androidnetworking:1.0.5.
 org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException:
> Could not resolve all files for configuration
> ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionNotFoundException: Could not
> find com.androidnetworking:androidnetworking:1.0.5.
```

> this is my build.gradle file and setting.gradle is there any thing i need to change -

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
}

android {
    namespace = "com.example.a15pickup"
    compileSdk = 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.a15pickup"
        minSdk = 28
        targetSdk = 33
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation ("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.2")
    implementation ("com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1")
    implementation ("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.9.3")
    implementation ("com.a:androidnetworking:1.0.5")
    implementation ("androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4")
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")
}
```

> And this is setting.gradle file -

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        maven { url = uri("https://jitpack.io") }        
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.name = "15pickup"
include(":app")
```

I tried changing the dependency (androidnetworking) and maven file in setting.gradel but it did not work i am still getting the same error